# New QMainWindow instances don't show up in taskbar

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

the first version of this code worked fine when working only with a single `QMainWindow` instance, but after trying to implement multiple instances I get some weird errors and bugs I can't understand after all day messing with them and scraping from similar questions.

This is the other question I had:

2. Using the [toolbar button](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nk1V1.png) directly, I can create as many instances as I'd like to; however, using its own shortcut, I get this error message after instantiating two windows:
   `QAction::event: Ambiguous shortcut overload: Ctrl+N`. The rest of shortcuts work fine so far. Instantiated `MainWindow`s don't have a taskbar icon either, only `w` (the latter is just an empty `NewWindow`, if I happen to do `w.show`). I compiled the code just in case, but there's still no associated taskbar icon for any window and still get shortcut overload.

Here's the part of the code that I believe causes these problems:

```
   <...>

   class NewWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        global window_list
        window_list = []  # Allow multiple MainWindow instances
        self.add_new_window()

    def add_new_window(self):
        window = MainWindow(self)
        window_list.append(window)
        window.show()

   # Ui_MainWindow is generated code
   # class Ui_MainWindow(object):
   #     def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
   class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__(window)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.window = window
        self.actionNew_Window.triggered.connect(self.window.add_new_window)
   
   if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = qtw.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = NewWindow()  # Instantiate window factory class

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Solution:

```
class NewWindow(QMainWindow):
 def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    global window_list
    window_list = []  # Allow multiple MainWindow instances
    self.add_new_window()

 def add_new_window(self):
    global window
    window = MainWindow(self)
    window_list.append(window)
    print(window_list)
    window.show()


class MainWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, window):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.window = window
        <...>

    self.actionNew_Window.triggered.connect(self.window.add_new_window)
```

Solution 2:

I also found the solution for the shortcut error. Now it has to be in Window context instead of Application:

```
self.actionNew_Window.setShortcutContext(QtCore.Qt.WindowShortcut)
```

Comment: You are still having the *same* issue as with your previous question. If you want to use separate windows, **do not add a parent to the constructor**.

Comment: When I don't pass `window` and just initialize it globally, I can't seem to access it in `MainWindow()` (`self.window = window` gives `name 'window' is not defined`) . Any thoughts?

Comment: That's because you're trying to access an argument that wasn't given. As already said, you should leave the `super().__init__()` constructor empty, then create the instance as you're already doing (with the `window` argument), so that you can access it from the instance but it will *not* be used for the super `__init__` constructor.

Comment: I added these changes but still have problems with the initialization order. I edited the question above.

Comment: For the last time, the `super().__init__()` must have **no arguments**. Leave the `window` argument in the `def __init__(self, window):` as you did before, but do **not** use that argument in the `super`.

Comment: Okay, it's working now, I really misunderstood what you meant. Thanks a lot!